# How to select one row when two or more consecutive rows have same statuses

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, etl, query-performance

Explanation:
I have a table that maintains data of sensors and their statuses (Running / Stopped) with date time. As shown in the below image:

[image]

I transform this data into this:

[image: -]

Using this query:

```
select * from (
Select A.TagName,
(select top 1 EventTime from PumpRunCounts_perf where status = 'Running' and EventTime<A.EventTime order by 1 desc) StartTime,
A.EventTime, A.Statuses
from (select * from PumpRunCounts_perf where status = 'Stopped')A
)A
```

The problem arises however when consecutive statuses are present, as shown below

[image]

What I want to achieve in consecutive statuses is that when consecutive 'Running' statuses are given, pick the most older one and when there are consecutive 'Stopped' statuses pick the latest one.

Like this:

[image]

I have used the cursors it gets the job done, but with over 50 hundred thousand rows it takes days to complete. Not sharing cursor code, for the sake of simplicity, let me know if required.

Please help me achieve this task. Thanks

Please see sample table schema and data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref](
    [ID] [nvarchar](36) NULL,
    [EventTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [Tagname] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](4000) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'C6A41E1E-2C5B-4A7A-8858-67EBA622DC24', CAST(N'2020-07-22T23:06:00.0700000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Stopped')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'EDDE7B77-4A59-4BE0-95F5-31532BF2CBA1', CAST(N'2020-07-21T12:06:45.5640000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Running')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'B44CAC7C-B648-44BD-9BC1-B647CE448124', CAST(N'2020-07-23T19:10:50.3870000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Running')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'093C6C46-2A38-4A71-83B2-FDF849B06016', CAST(N'2020-07-18T05:54:52.7430000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Running')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'69A1610E-6859-4C56-845C-0A4EFF215A41', CAST(N'2020-07-20T04:59:45.2150000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Running')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'37DD901A-F2A0-4142-887D-D22CB38BB1F2', CAST(N'2020-07-20T03:19:40.7580000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Stopped')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'1D3F54F6-A129-43BB-B30B-4782AB587711', CAST(N'2020-07-24T03:39:44.4840000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Stopped')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'8A9C9058-4721-4C4F-A0D4-0B93B48AEC1A', CAST(N'2020-07-22T01:57:20.8030000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Stopped')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'A41E1295-C196-4E24-BDF4-62FC0B321BE3', CAST(N'2020-07-23T10:36:46.2140000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Stopped')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'7EAB2F61-EC61-448B-AA41-5C097C2F01EE', CAST(N'2020-07-20T13:41:35.4600000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Running')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'75746488-03B4-4639-B1AD-9882297B8FA6', CAST(N'2020-07-23T20:01:12.6110000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Running')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'3ADA8A20-0E79-4AAA-A7A7-FC17C7FC21E4', CAST(N'2020-07-19T04:12:21.9360000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Stopped')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'4CCEF052-46B1-4674-8278-C6649FD42C85', CAST(N'2020-07-23T10:10:33.3180000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Running')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'707EB5F2-CF3B-4699-9C59-C883615897C5', CAST(N'2020-07-21T21:54:10.1870000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Stopped')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'E7104F6D-82E3-49F5-B446-6A371A1E558A', CAST(N'2020-07-21T21:05:57.5550000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Stopped')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'23358E48-E947-4273-ACCC-E52A0A8DB137', CAST(N'2020-07-22T16:33:22.3440000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Running')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'274C023F-5E7B-4626-AD96-CA9BB42EE6A0', CAST(N'2020-07-22T03:34:21.3950000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Stopped')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'C58C6FB7-478E-4E32-AB08-535218AC3306', CAST(N'2020-07-24T04:12:08.0600000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Stopped')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'3F4E8D3C-0101-4A74-93CC-922F7700C83B', CAST(N'2020-07-20T19:04:40.4240000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Stopped')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'A1C363E2-3F14-4F9A-80B8-DC8B6634C2AB', CAST(N'2020-07-20T22:20:48.7130000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Stopped')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'95DC2DD7-CD27-4783-864D-4287A90DEDB3', CAST(N'2020-07-19T21:27:06.5570000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Stopped')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'9D3BAA7D-569D-414C-ADE0-F5263BACE1FF', CAST(N'2020-07-20T16:39:15.2270000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Stopped')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'B1C3AE46-3713-40A9-BA46-C3209EB7120C', CAST(N'2020-07-24T04:40:33.3250000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Running')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'DC1F0A0A-D767-494F-968A-07B6823CB26D', CAST(N'2020-07-20T20:14:50.2330000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Running')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'B497FA37-0E0F-4C19-9DF3-16735799ED02', CAST(N'2020-07-19T14:25:49.0880000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Stopped')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'CAAED751-4EE5-4FEF-98E2-0EEE8243CC1C', CAST(N'2020-07-22T04:06:56.9780000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Stopped')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'46258565-5C3F-45FB-AA36-78E3AAE0E88B', CAST(N'2020-07-23T03:43:54.3460000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Running')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'F7A1DB90-11D0-489F-A7BF-3D882153C6F3', CAST(N'2020-07-21T04:13:58.3370000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Running')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'38496DC3-BC8D-4D4C-9F0F-A0FC6285C009', CAST(N'2020-07-24T04:06:56.3970000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Running')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'3FE2CA7D-D059-403C-8BF2-9E2167B2D758', CAST(N'2020-07-23T17:26:22.8540000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Running')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'EB1591B1-73D8-4755-9B4C-0222ADA4BA2D', CAST(N'2020-07-18T05:59:27.6120000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Stopped')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'44743BDB-E084-4B5F-86A0-99812EC1452D', CAST(N'2020-07-19T04:08:14.9520000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Running')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'C9AC6855-1BDF-4B5C-9514-1CAE0D86E1D0', CAST(N'2020-07-22T20:51:39.3850000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Running')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'7E65B1CD-EE80-48C7-8DFD-F5A0F8C1D4E5', CAST(N'2020-07-18T16:44:55.2720000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Stopped')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'0CAFDFDF-CA04-4B8E-81FD-E54C96338120', CAST(N'2020-07-23T02:42:17.7990000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Stopped')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'DE7EA0C5-2EB9-4433-B99D-253711F0D990', CAST(N'2020-07-22T03:29:24.8290000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Running')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'DB459A4A-F03E-4911-9134-AB74C5763A29', CAST(N'2020-07-19T15:59:08.0170000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Running')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'C0AAABE7-D3C8-4E58-8501-44F2807992F0', CAST(N'2020-07-21T03:37:42.8400000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Running')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'F9E84C95-D1B8-42BE-8E51-A1E5BC63823C', CAST(N'2020-07-22T02:22:35.4930000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Running')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'3C12D9B6-38FC-4CD0-B668-EC583D072DC0', CAST(N'2020-07-21T02:30:25.0890000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Running')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'D8B005DF-3443-49BD-ACFD-803CFDDEF58D', CAST(N'2020-07-21T04:47:35.6360000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Running')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'3D6D5222-9B25-45C1-A73A-2E31F9DED4E3', CAST(N'2020-07-23T15:16:24.2680000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Stopped')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'F9EC2A51-0F1F-4BCB-8FAE-DE70B89BB590', CAST(N'2020-07-23T16:56:09.4620000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Stopped')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'433A4288-2FE3-4C7B-9205-16E98D1A376B', CAST(N'2020-07-19T14:47:55.5760000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Running')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'D05ED43A-244F-43B5-B778-38442CF2F6A4', CAST(N'2020-07-22T23:06:41.4140000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Stopped')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'D1399731-0F0F-4019-A8A5-12A7E2CD9D36', CAST(N'2020-07-21T04:18:24.7070000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Stopped')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'B8231929-2062-45A4-A7E6-939EF4E994F2', CAST(N'2020-07-20T04:29:50.5050000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Stopped')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'5D88B78F-6178-4B4E-8ACA-FD888E916DB5', CAST(N'2020-07-22T10:33:41.0020000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Running')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'4FB517BD-401C-451A-AE35-EEF80D5262AE', CAST(N'2020-07-22T04:01:47.3900000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Running')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[pumpruncounts_pref] ([ID], [EventTime], [Tagname], [Status]) VALUES (N'3E673EB3-BC3D-40B7-9BDA-ABDF192CE012', CAST(N'2020-07-22T20:28:47.4780000' AS DateTime2), N'PS44_P06.RunS', N'Stopped')
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems odd to me that you want the *later* stopped row rather than the first.  But that is the question you asked here.

One approach uses `lag()` and `lead()` to keep only the "Running" row following a stopped (or NULL) and "Stopped" rows where the next row is "Running" (or NULL).

Then a simple `lead()` and filter gets what you want:

```
select tagname, eventtime as starttime, next_eventtime as endtime
from (select p.*,
             lead(eventtime) over (partition by tagname order by eventtime) as next_eventtime
      from (select p.*,
                   lag(status) over (partition by tagname order by eventtime) as prev_status,
                   lead(status) over (partition by tagname order by eventtime) as next_status
            from pumpruncounts_pref p
           ) p
      where ( status = 'Running' and (prev_status is null or prev_status = 'Stopped') ) or
            ( status = 'Stopped' and (next_status is null or next_status = 'Running') )
     ) p
where status = 'Running';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ad5282fa6e7641f687e783a7a7dbac34) is a db<>fiddle.

If you actually want the *first* stop in a sequence (which makes more sense to me), then you can tweak the logic for stops to mimic the starts (i.e. looking at the previous row rather than the next).

For performance, add an index on `(tagname, eventtime, status)`.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon for the help. I have tested it on complete data and it returns the correct result. Query takes some 20 mins to execute on 50 hundred thousand rows. Could you give any tips if execution time could be lowered? Thank you.

Comment: @Miru . . . That seems like a very long time.  I suggest an index in the answer, but perhaps something else is going on with your system.  In particular, perhaps `pumpruncounts_pref` is a view that is really a very complicated query.

Answer (score 1):

Or use the start and stop, their predecessors and successors to identify start, running and end; then add a running sum of 1 each time you encounter a "real" start, use that running sum as a session identifier, and finally group by tag name and session id.

Your input in an opening Common Table Expression, just after the `WITH` keyword,
then two follow-up CTE-s - showing the intermediate results - and finally the GROUP BY query.

```
WITH
pumpruncounts_pref(id,eventtime,tagname,status) AS (
          SELECT 'C9AC6855-1BDF-4B5C-9514-1CAE0D86E1D0', TIMESTAMP '2020-07-22T20:51:39.3850000', 'PS44_P06.RunS', 'Running'
UNION ALL SELECT '7E65B1CD-EE80-48C7-8DFD-F5A0F8C1D4E5', TIMESTAMP '2020-07-18T16:44:55.2720000', 'PS44_P06.RunS', 'Stopped'
UNION ALL SELECT '0CAFDFDF-CA04-4B8E-81FD-E54C96338120', TIMESTAMP '2020-07-23T02:42:17.7990000', 'PS44_P06.RunS', 'Stopped'
UNION ALL SELECT 'DE7EA0C5-2EB9-4433-B99D-253711F0D990', TIMESTAMP '2020-07-22T03:29:24.8290000', 'PS44_P06.RunS', 'Running'
UNION ALL SELECT 'DB459A4A-F03E-4911-9134-AB74C5763A29', TIMESTAMP '2020-07-19T15:59:08.0170000', 'PS44_P06.RunS', 'Running'
UNION ALL SELECT 'C0AAABE7-D3C8-4E58-8501-44F2807992F0', TIMESTAMP '2020-07-21T03:37:42.8400000', 'PS44_P06.RunS', 'Running'
UNION ALL SELECT 'F9E84C95-D1B8-42BE-8E51-A1E5BC63823C', TIMESTAMP '2020-07-22T02:22:35.4930000', 'PS44_P06.RunS', 'Running'
UNION ALL SELECT '3C12D9B6-38FC-4CD0-B668-EC583D072DC0', TIMESTAMP '2020-07-21T02:30:25.0890000', 'PS44_P06.RunS', 'Running'
UNION ALL SELECT 'D8B005DF-3443-49BD-ACFD-803CFDDEF58D', TIMESTAMP '2020-07-21T04:47:35.6360000', 'PS44_P06.RunS', 'Running'
UNION ALL SELECT '3D6D5222-9B25-45C1-A73A-2E31F9DED4E3', TIMESTAMP '2020-07-23T15:16:24.2680000', 'PS44_P06.RunS', 'Stopped'
UNION ALL SELECT 'F9EC2A51-0F1F-4BCB-8FAE-DE70B89BB590', TIMESTAMP '2020-07-23T16:56:09.4620000', 'PS44_P06.RunS', 'Stopped'
UNION ALL SELECT '433A4288-2FE3-4C7B-9205-16E98D1A376B', TIMESTAMP '2020-07-19T14:47:55.5760000', 'PS44_P06.RunS', 'Running'
UNION ALL SELECT 'D05ED43A-244F-43B5-B778-38442CF2F6A4', TIMESTAMP '2020-07-22T23:06:41.4140000', 'PS44_P06.RunS', 'Stopped'
UNION ALL SELECT 'D1399731-0F0F-4019-A8A5-12A7E2CD9D36', TIMESTAMP '2020-07-21T04:18:24.7070000', 'PS44_P06.RunS', 'Stopped'
UNION ALL SELECT 'B8231929-2062-45A4-A7E6-939EF4E994F2', TIMESTAMP '2020-07-20T04:29:50.5050000', 'PS44_P06.RunS', 'Stopped'
UNION ALL SELECT '5D88B78F-6178-4B4E-8ACA-FD888E916DB5', TIMESTAMP '2020-07-22T10:33:41.0020000', 'PS44_P06.RunS', 'Running'
UNION ALL SELECT '4FB517BD-401C-451A-AE35-EEF80D5262AE', TIMESTAMP '2020-07-22T04:01:47.3900000', 'PS44_P06.RunS', 'Running'
UNION ALL SELECT '3E673EB3-BC3D-40B7-9BDA-ABDF192CE012', TIMESTAMP '2020-07-22T20:28:47.4780000', 'PS44_P06.RunS', 'Stopped'
)
,
with_chg AS (
  SELECT
    eventtime
  , tagname
  , status
  , CASE 
      WHEN ISNULL(LAG(status) OVER(PARTITION BY tagname ORDER BY eventtime),'Stopped')='Stopped'
       AND status='Running'
      THEN 'Start'
      WHEN ISNULL(LEAD(status) OVER(PARTITION BY tagname ORDER BY eventtime),'Running')='Running'
       AND status='Stopped'
      THEN 'Stop'
      ELSE 'Running'
    END AS newstat
  FROM pumpruncounts_pref
)
-- out         eventtime        |    tagname    | status  | newstat 
-- out -------------------------+---------------+---------+---------
-- out  2020-07-18 16:44:55.272 | PS44_P06.RunS | Stopped | Stop
-- out  2020-07-19 14:47:55.576 | PS44_P06.RunS | Running | Start
-- out  2020-07-19 15:59:08.017 | PS44_P06.RunS | Running | Running
-- out  2020-07-20 04:29:50.505 | PS44_P06.RunS | Stopped | Stop
-- out  2020-07-21 02:30:25.089 | PS44_P06.RunS | Running | Start
-- out  2020-07-21 03:37:42.84  | PS44_P06.RunS | Running | Running
-- out  2020-07-21 04:18:24.707 | PS44_P06.RunS | Stopped | Stop
-- out  2020-07-21 04:47:35.636 | PS44_P06.RunS | Running | Start
-- out  2020-07-22 02:22:35.493 | PS44_P06.RunS | Running | Running
-- out  2020-07-22 03:29:24.829 | PS44_P06.RunS | Running | Running
-- out  2020-07-22 04:01:47.39  | PS44_P06.RunS | Running | Running
-- out  2020-07-22 10:33:41.002 | PS44_P06.RunS | Running | Running
-- out  2020-07-22 20:28:47.478 | PS44_P06.RunS | Stopped | Stop
-- out  2020-07-22 20:51:39.385 | PS44_P06.RunS | Running | Start
-- out  2020-07-22 23:06:41.414 | PS44_P06.RunS | Stopped | Running
-- out  2020-07-23 02:42:17.799 | PS44_P06.RunS | Stopped | Running
-- out  2020-07-23 15:16:24.268 | PS44_P06.RunS | Stopped | Running
-- out  2020-07-23 16:56:09.462 | PS44_P06.RunS | Stopped | Stop
-- out (18 rows)
-- out 
-- out Time: First fetch (18 rows): 24.252 ms. All rows formatted: 24.307 ms
,
with_session AS (
  SELECT
    eventtime
  , tagname
  , status
  , newstat
  , SUM(
      CASE newstat
        WHEN 'Start' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END
    ) OVER (PARTITION BY tagname ORDER BY eventtime) AS session_id
  FROM with_chg
)
-- out         eventtime        |    tagname    | status  | newstat | session_id 
-- out -------------------------+---------------+---------+---------+------------
-- out  2020-07-18 16:44:55.272 | PS44_P06.RunS | Stopped | Stop    |          0
-- out  2020-07-19 14:47:55.576 | PS44_P06.RunS | Running | Start   |          1
-- out  2020-07-19 15:59:08.017 | PS44_P06.RunS | Running | Running |          1
-- out  2020-07-20 04:29:50.505 | PS44_P06.RunS | Stopped | Stop    |          1
-- out  2020-07-21 02:30:25.089 | PS44_P06.RunS | Running | Start   |          2
-- out  2020-07-21 03:37:42.84  | PS44_P06.RunS | Running | Running |          2
-- out  2020-07-21 04:18:24.707 | PS44_P06.RunS | Stopped | Stop    |          2
-- out  2020-07-21 04:47:35.636 | PS44_P06.RunS | Running | Start   |          3
-- out  2020-07-22 02:22:35.493 | PS44_P06.RunS | Running | Running |          3
-- out  2020-07-22 03:29:24.829 | PS44_P06.RunS | Running | Running |          3
-- out  2020-07-22 04:01:47.39  | PS44_P06.RunS | Running | Running |          3
-- out  2020-07-22 10:33:41.002 | PS44_P06.RunS | Running | Running |          3
-- out  2020-07-22 20:28:47.478 | PS44_P06.RunS | Stopped | Stop    |          3
-- out  2020-07-22 20:51:39.385 | PS44_P06.RunS | Running | Start   |          4
-- out  2020-07-22 23:06:41.414 | PS44_P06.RunS | Stopped | Running |          4
-- out  2020-07-23 02:42:17.799 | PS44_P06.RunS | Stopped | Running |          4
-- out  2020-07-23 15:16:24.268 | PS44_P06.RunS | Stopped | Running |          4
-- out  2020-07-23 16:56:09.462 | PS44_P06.RunS | Stopped | Stop    |          4
SELECT
  tagname
, session_id
, MIN(eventtime) AS start_ts
, MAX(eventtime) AS end_ts
FROM with_session
GROUP BY
  tagname
, session_id
ORDER BY
  tagname
, session_id
-- out     tagname    | session_id |        start_ts         |         end_ts          
-- out ---------------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------
-- out  PS44_P06.RunS |          0 | 2020-07-18 16:44:55.272 | 2020-07-18 16:44:55.272
-- out  PS44_P06.RunS |          1 | 2020-07-19 14:47:55.576 | 2020-07-20 04:29:50.505
-- out  PS44_P06.RunS |          2 | 2020-07-21 02:30:25.089 | 2020-07-21 04:18:24.707
-- out  PS44_P06.RunS |          3 | 2020-07-21 04:47:35.636 | 2020-07-22 20:28:47.478
-- out  PS44_P06.RunS |          4 | 2020-07-22 20:51:39.385 | 2020-07-23 16:56:09.462
```

Comment: Thanks marcothesane.

I will go will the Gordon answer, it is much manageable for me.

Thank you for helping.